# My dropdown is displayed but the content/filter is not printed out

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css

How can I display the content of my dropdown. Because for now, the dropdown is displayed but the options `Good`, `Medium`, `Bad`, `Critical` are not printed out.

```
export default function Info({ onValidation, display }) {
  const LEVEL = [
    { name: "Good", value: "Good" },
    { name: "Medium", value: "Medium" },
    { name: "Bad", value: "Bad" },
    { name: "Critical", value: "Critical" }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center">
      <CustomDropdown options={LEVEL} isMulti={true} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

CustomDropdown:

```
export default function CustomDropdown({ className, style, options, styleSelect, defaultValue, isMulti = false }) {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(defaultValue);

    const styles = {
        select: {
            width: '100%',
            maxWidth: 200,
        }
    }

    return <div style={style} >
        {selected && isMulti === false ?
            <Tag selected={selected} setSelected={setSelected} styleSelect={styleSelect} />
            :
            <Select className={className} style={styles.select} value={selected} onChange={setSelected} options={options} isMulti={isMulti} />
        }
    </div>
}
```

Tag.jsx :

```
export default function Tag({ selected, setSelected, styleSelect }) {
  const backgroundColor = styleSelect?.(selected?.label) ?? "grey";
  return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around", padding: "0.1em", backgroundColor: backgroundColor, borderRadius: "4px", color: "white", marginRight: "20px", marginLeft: "4px", marginBottom: "8px" }}>
          {selected.label}
          <button
              style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent", color: "white", border: "none", cursor: "pointer", marginRight: "1px", marginLeft: "6px" }}
              onClick={() => setSelected(null)}>x</button>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-ganguly-l7zhm4?)

Comment: Your options have names but not labels. Did you mean `selected.name`?

Comment: Files in your codesandbox are empty, update please

Comment: @rayhatfield  so I have to change name by label then ?

Comment: @Evren I've update it sorry.

Comment: you forget to add  parentheses after `return` keyword in CustomDropdown

Comment: parens aren't required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change below code From:

```
export default function Info({ onValidation, display }) {
  const LEVEL = [
    { name: "Good", value: "Good" },
    { name: "Medium", value: "Medium" },
    { name: "Bad", value: "Bad" },
    { name: "Critical", value: "Critical" }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center">
      <CustomDropdown options={LEVEL} isMulti={true} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

To:

```
export default function Info({ onValidation, display }) {
  const LEVEL = [
    { label: "Good", value: "Good" },
    { label: "Medium", value: "Medium" },
    { label: "Bad", value: "Bad" },
    { label: "Critical", value: "Critical" }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center">
      <CustomDropdown options={LEVEL} isMulti={true} />
    </div>
  );
}
```